# Show a form after Application Load

Tags: vb.net

I want to show a dialog box or form immediately after my application loads. If I place a .showdialog in the main form load event the dialog shows before the application shows.

I’m trying to give some user tips when they load my application.

Thanks

Comment: Further reading, order of form events:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shown event is pretty much designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the dialog form invocation in the Form_Activate event of your main form.

Comment: Activate fires continuously well the form is active. The Shown Event fires once.